# How to communicate with NCI NFC controller over serial?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, nfc

I'm trying to get a handle on my TRF7970A NFC reader for a custom application. It is being controlled by a MSP432P401R and as far as I understand it should have full NCI support.

Libs exist for specific for the PNxxx hardware but I can't find anything NCI generic over serial.

Neard doesn't seem to be picking up anything automatically and I can't seem to find any mechanism to configure neard specifically for NCI over serial.

If anybody can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, TRF7970A does not implement NCI. [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slos743l/slos743l.pdf) chapter 6.10 seems to confirm that.

Ti seems to [provide relevant patches](http://www.ti.com/tool/linux-nfc-trf7970a) for making it work with Neard. I've not tested it myself.